# Initialization of std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How can I initialize an `initializer_list` compound of unordered elements?
For example, consider the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using Type = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>;
void foo(std::initializer_list<Type> l) {}

int main()
{
    Type x = {{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}};  // compile fine
    // std::initializer_list<Type> y = {{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}};
    // foo({{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}});
}
```

If I uncomment the first line, I got (g++ 6.1.1) the error:

> error: could not convert ‘{{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}’ from ‘’ to ‘std::initializer_list, int> >’
>        std::initializer_list y = {{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}};

At the end, what I want to do is to be able to call `foo` like the second commented line, which doesn't compile too.

Comment: `foo({{{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a set of {}.  You need to have

```
{{{"xxx", 0}}, {{"yyy", 1}}}
```

The inside `{}` creates a `std::pair<std::string, int>` for the `std::inializer_list<std::pair<std::string, int>>` the map is constructed from.  The next level up creates each map for the `std::inializer_list<std::pair<std::string, int>>`to construct each map in the `std::initializer_list<Type>`.  The outer most `{}` is the extent of the `std::initializer_list<Type>`.  We can expand that to

```
foo({{{"xxx", 0}}, {{"yyy", 1},{"zzz", 2}}});
```

which is a `std::initializer_list<Type>` where the first map has one entry and the second map has 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some braces.  `{{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}` is a fine initializer for a `Type`, but for a list of `Type`s containing just one `unordered_map`, you need

```
{{{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}}
```

Or for a list of `Type`s containing two `unordered_map`s each with one pair,

```
{{{"xxx", 0}}, {{"yyy", 1}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In line number 2, you are attempting to initialize a std::initializer_list of std::unordered_map's, but you are giving it the arguments for just the unordered_map. Adding another set of braces would fix the issue.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using Type = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>;
void foo(std::initializer_list<Type> l) {}

int main()
{
    Type x = {{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}};  // compile fine
    //initialization for std::unordered_map<std::string, int>
    // std::initializer_list<Type> y = {{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}; 

    //correct initialization, each std::unordered_map has exactly 1 element in it
    std::initializer_list<Type> y = { {{"xxx", 0}}, {{"yyy", 1}}}

    // foo({{"xxx", 0}, {"yyy", 1}}); //As before
    foo({{{"xxx", 0}}, {"yyy", 1}}}); //Correct call
}
```